# What are all of the currently known variations of the G zipper motif?

Tags: biochemistry, proteins, cell-membrane

The G zipper motif is found in transmembrane proteins at an above [random frequency](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10677292) and there are [models explaining how it might help with multiple transmembrane intra-membrane helix bundle assembly](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1242278/).

However there are a bunch of different "flavours" of these G zipper motifs. Here are the ones I have come across so far:

- GXXXG
- GVXXGV
- GXXXGXXXG
- AXXXGXXXG
- SXXXGXXXG
- GXXXGXXXS
- GXXXGXXXT

I don't think I am completely up to date so that is a non-exhaustive list. Have I missed any? Broadly speaking what accounts for their variation?

*note: [X refers to a non specific amino acid in FASTA protein sequences.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format#Sequence_representation)*

Comment: It seems to be a small family as per pfam. And frankly I had never heard of glycine zippers till now (so thanks for that). Perhaps [this](http://pfam.xfam.org/clan/Glycine-zipper#tabview=tab2) may be useful.